# How To Get Last Key's Value Of JSON data In SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a `Json` data in key value pair in `sql`. I want Last Key Value from that `json`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
         ID,Code,JSON_QUERY(B.[value]) AS options
FROM OPENJSON(Json) WITH (ID nvarchar(max),Code nvarchar(max),Json nvarchar(max), options NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) D
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(D.Json) B
ORDER BY B.[key] DESC
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

I have `Json` data like this.

```
{"98934889":"Date: 08/16/2017","5551099988":"This is First comment","5454454545":"This is Second comment"}
```

I Want result `"This is second Comment"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved such result with

```
SELECT TOP 1
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by [Id]) AS [RowNum],
*
FROM 
[dbo].[Logs]
CROSS APPLY
OPENJSON([RawMessage])
WHERE [Id] = 340519
ORDER BY
[RowNum] DESC
```

Where [Id] is same for all cross apply rows. For one specific row (replace with variable)

If you wanna retrieve last preperty value in JSON for multiple rows, you can try this

```
SELECT *
FROM

(SELECT 
    Max(RowNum) AS [MaxRow],
    [Id]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by [Id] Order by [Id]) AS [RowNum],
        [Id]

        FROM 
        [dbo].[Logs]
        CROSS APPLY
        OPENJSON([RawMessage])

        --WHERE [Id] in (340519,347307)

    ) AS [Qinner]
    GROUP BY
    [Id]
) as [Q1]

LEFT JOIN

(
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by [Id] Order by [Id]) AS [RowNum],
    [Id],
    [ProcessName],
    [OrganizationUnitId],
    [key],
    [value]

    FROM 
    [dbo].[Logs]
    CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON([RawMessage])

    --WHERE [Id] in (340519,347307)

) AS [Q2]

ON
[Q1].[Id]= [Q2].[Id] AND
[Q1].[MaxRow] = [Q2].[RowNum]
```

I retrieve value of last row counted per [Id] (row), and I join it on table that has CROSS APPLY result for OPENJSON with row count.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Next approach is based on the fact, that when `OPENJSON` is used with default schema and the `JSON` is an array of `JSON` objects, the [result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value) is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the `key` columns holds the index of the element in this `JSON` array. The important part here is the fact, that `JSON` must be a valid `JSON` array.

In your case you need to transform your `JSON` into a valid `JSON` array of objects (`{"a": 1, "b": 2}` is transformed into `[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}]` for example).

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"98934889":"Date: 08/16/2017","5551099988":"This is First comment","5454454545":"This is Second comment"}'

SELECT TOP 1 j2.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'[', REPLACE(@json, N',', N'},{'), N']')) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
ORDER BY j1.[key] DESC
```

Output:

```
----------------------
value
----------------------
This is Second comment
```

**Solution 2:**

You may use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `CHARINDEX()` to order the results from `OPENJSON()`:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"98934889":"Date: 08/16/2017","5551099988":"This is First comment","5454454545":"This is Second comment"}'

SELECT TOP 1 t.[value]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(CONCAT(N'"', [key], N'":'), @json)) AS Rn
   FROM OPENJSON(@json)
) t
ORDER BY t.Rn DESC
```

**Notes:**

Using `.. ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ...` seems to be an option here, but it's not guaranteed that the rows will be ordered as in the original `JSON` (there is nothing in documentation that guarantees this, in cases when `JSON` is not a `JSON` array).

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"98934889":"Date: 08/16/2017","5551099988":"This is First comment","5454454545":"This is Second comment"}'

SELECT TOP 1 t.[value]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Rn
   FROM OPENJSON(@json)
) t
ORDER BY t.Rn DESC
```